# @Update doesn't update entity room

Tags: android-studio, android-room

I am making an app and I wanten to update an existing entity but the @Update method from room always returns 0 as value. So no rows were updated.

Dao:

```
@Update
int updateNote(Note note);
```

Repository:

```
void updateNote(Note note){
    new updateAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

private static class updateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {
    private NoteDao asyncTaskNoteDao;

    updateAsyncTask(NoteDao dao) {
        asyncTaskNoteDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Note... params) {
        asyncTaskNoteDao.updateNote(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If anybody knows how this works, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding @Update annotation like below, it's set to replace in case of conflict (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)

Dao:

```
@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
int updateNote(Note note);
```

"REPLACE:
When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command continues executing normally"

OnConflictStrategy Android Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy

SQLite conflict documentation:
https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html